# Sidebar links unclickable, unselectable

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty comfortable with basic html/css, but I've been really tripped up by a problem in a tumblr theme I'm working on. The text in my sidebar can't be selected, and the links do not work. I've read about people having problems where they put a div inside of a span tag, or because of a position:absolute, but I don't think that either of those are the issue. You can view the very unfinished site [here](http://chelseaborg.com).

Edit: including the relevant code

```
<header id="masthead">
<div id="header">
    {block:IfMastheadPortrait}
    <img src="{PortraitURL-128}"/>
    {/block:IfMastheadPortrait}
    <div id="big"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com" title="{lang:Home}">{Title}</a></div>
    <div id="goto"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com/about">About</a> // 
    <a href="http://chelseaborg.com/submit">Contact</a></div>
    {block:Description}
    <p>{Description}</p>
    {block:Description}
</div>
<!--Navigation-->
<nav>

    <div id="linx"> 
   <span style="background-color: #007A5E"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com/tagged/design">Design</a></span>
<br />
    <span style="background-color: #007A5E"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com/tagged/drawing">Drawing & Painting</a></span>
<br />
<span style="background-color: #007A5E"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com/tagged/photo"> Photography</a></span>
<br />
<span style="background-color: #007A5E"><a href="http://chelseaborg.com/tagged/mix">Mixed Media</a></span>
</div>
    <br />
</nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS

```
#big {
color: {color:Masthead links};
font-size: 40px;
font-family: 'Codystar', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
#masthead {
background: {color:Masthead background} url('{image:Masthead}');
opacity: 0.7;
padding: 2%;
color: {color:Masthead text};
font-size:10.5px;
width: 180px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
float:left;
xmargin: {text:Post margin};


}
#masthead a {
color: {color:Masthead links};
}
nav li {
display: inline;
}
#linx {
text-align:center;
font-size:15px;
line-height:1.5;
font-family: {font:body} ;
color: #007A5E;
}
#linx a {
color:#000;
}
#goto {
text-align:center;
line-height:3;
}
#goto a {
color:#00A37D;
}
```

Comment: Having code to view as well is always useful in finding and fixing issues

Comment: use firebug to identify your problem.

Comment: Your links work fine in your [about me](http://chelseaborg.com/about) page.  Try copying and pasting your code from there to here.  Could just be a small typo causing this bug.

Comment: Most of them work... `About me` link and `Contact` don't work but the others below it do.

Comment: The cause of this is because you have `position: relative` on `#content`, if u remove that the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the sidebar a `z-index` so it sits on top of `#content`:

```
#masthead {      
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Just a heads up, `xmargin` isn't a thing. :D

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it worked! Also haha I'm aware xmargin isn't a thing, I put the x in front to turn off that particular line instead of deleting it, in case I want to use it in the future.

Comment: Ahh, good thinking batman! Good luck with the rest of the theme.